# Battery Indicator not displaying on Ubuntu Gnome 18.04 Top Bar

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-shell

I installed Ubuntu Gnome two days ago and everything is working fine besides the battery indicator. For some reason in the top bar it does not show even when using gnome tweaks to turn it on.

I have used the command:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

Returning:

```
native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Thu 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 IST (1573663817 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

This shows that it can't even see a power supply never mind the battery percentage.

I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the battery indicator multiples times and it is fully up to date. And also have updated Ubuntu and updated all the packages that need to be upgraded.

After searching online I found that it may have to do with the autostart folder which **does not** contain the battery indicator, so it probably has something to do with that.

Path to autostart file:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart
```

I would appreciate any suggestion even if you think it is not the autostart problem. Thanks.

### My System

```
Linux pc 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
description: Laptop
    product: Surface Pro 6 (Surface_Pro_6_1796_Consumer)
    vendor: Microsoft Corporation
    version: D:0B:13F:5C:10P:38S:01E:0
    serial: 051670285253
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.1 dmi-3.1 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=laptop family=Surface sku=Surface_Pro_6_1796_Consumer uuid=0A1BA476-28B9-228A-191E-C19E0DDDAF06
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Surface Pro 6
       vendor: Microsoft Corporation
       physical id: 0
       serial: A75493112764852A
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Microsoft Corporation
          physical id: 0
          version: 234.2706.768
          date: 04/18/2019
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 6
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is not a battery problem, is about the surface headers in linux. I solved it by installing a new kernel (very easy), the link is: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack-overflow . you can use this link for improve your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/tour